# How to detect Square Reader Hardware is connected with iPad via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, square-connect, square-reader

I'm developing an iOS app using Square Reader SDK, how will I detect whether the Square Reader Hardware is connected with the device, so that I can show Square Reader Settings View in case of the hardware is not connected with the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
let readerSettingsController = SQRDReaderSettingsController(delegate: self)
readerSettingsController.present(from: self)
```

If you are done with other required process, Simply put above code to check status about card reader connection.

Comment: Hi Punit, thanks for the comment. But I guess SQRDReaderSettingsController displays the settings view of the reader. It is not returning whether the device is connected via Bluetooth or not.

Comment: yes, thats true. So there is no other way to detect it.